# Imageview looks different on different size and density

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've made a Viewpager with swipe-able fragments where you can see a partial view of the other fragment. The fragments have a single imageview and that is what is shown. I've tried running my code on different emulators and the result is always different. How can I make it so it looks the same on all screen sizes?
This is the fragment containing the viewpager and buttons:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.example.digital05.masu.Fragments.MassageViewFragment">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/massageViewPager"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/buttonDate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/massageViewPager"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonTime"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonTime"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time"
    android:id="@+id/buttonTime"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonDate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

This is how the fragments look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.digital05.masu.Fragments.SwedishMFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:src="@drawable/prenatal_massage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

And this is how I set the viewpager to show the partial view of other fragments(their imageviews):

```
mViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
mViewPager.setPadding(300, 0, 300, 0);
mViewPager.setPageMargin(50);
```

And this is the output I get:

[image]

How can I make it so all of them look the same like on the Nexus 6P? Do I need to convert the dp to px or vice versa and how to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd use the PercentRelativeLayout and and the set the scaleType to fit

Comment: Where exactly should I use that?

Comment: check this blog, https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days trying, I've managed to make it work.
I've put the value for mViewPager.setPageMargin() in dimens.xml as dp. Then, I created dimens hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi folders which have different values for the setPageMargin. This way, different types of emulators/phones will use different files and the images will look almost the same on all of them.

This way it works like a charm!

Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You set padding and margin for `ViewPager` with raw number you should convert them to DP by this way in every screen they look the same.

```
   float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;


 public static int dp(float value) {
        if (value == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (int) Math.ceil(density * value);
    }
```

Also there is Another way by use of [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library by following code you can get proper value :

```
@BindDimen(R.dimen.your_dimen_value)
int myPadding;
```

If you need help understanding DP's, check here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you care to show me how to convert them?

Comment: @jlively does your problem fixed ? Also for your image set their scaleType to centerCrop.

Comment: No, I can't make it to work. I use this
public int pxToDp(int px){
return (int) (px/ Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
And then 
int dp = pxToDp(350);
        mViewPager.setPadding(dp, 0, dp, 0);
        int margin = pxToDp(300);
        mViewPager.setPageMargin(-margin);

Like this, it's fine on a Nexus5, but they change on a Nexus 4 or Nexus 6. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I update my code the previous code was for converting px2Dp. Use DP method and it will be fixed.

Comment: Sure, I will try it now. Since I am a beginner can you please let me know what variable type is density in your code?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this does not solve my problem.